# Airflow 2.0 Warnings after db init

Tags: airflow

I deployed Airflow 2.0 on ubuntu using pip commands. Have migrated from 1.10.13 to 2.0. But after db inint , I am getting below warnings. Please suggest why am I getting these warnings.
I tried running example dags and they run successfully.

```
WARNI [airflow.providers_manager] The provider for package 'apache-airflow-providers-http' could not be registered from because providers for that package name have already been registered
WARNI [airflow.providers_manager] The provider for package 'apache-airflow-providers-sqlite' could not be registered from because providers for that package name have already been registered
WARNI [airflow.providers_manager] The provider for package 'apache-airflow-providers-imap' could not be registered from because providers for that package name have already been registered
WARNI [airflow.providers_manager] The provider for package 'apache-airflow-providers-ftp' could not be registered from because providers for that package name have already been registered
WARNI [airflow.providers_manager] The provider for package 'apache-airflow-providers-http' could not be registered from because providers for that package name have already been registered
WARNI [airflow.providers_manager] The provider for package 'apache-airflow-providers-sqlite' could not be registered from because providers for that package name have already been registered
WARNI [airflow.providers_manager] The provider for package 'apache-airflow-providers-imap' could not be registered from because providers for that package name have already been registered
WARNI [airflow.providers_manager] The provider for package 'apache-airflow-providers-ftp' could not be registered from because providers for that package name have already been registered
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a kind of installation where you have both "provider packages" installed and Airflow with source code with providers in the **PYTHONPATH**. I guess you installed Airflow from sources with `-e` flag rather than from the PyPI package in which case you will get those warning.

BTW. Those warnings will be gone in 2.0.1 https://github.com/apache/airflow/commit/18df31d5d451299c510a9bf11946f17471f1e573

The warnings are harmless - but then the providers that are installed as packages are not used (the ones from airflow sources are).

The root cause of it that if you want to install Airflow as editable install from sources (basically when you want to contribute to Airflow) you should set `INSTALL_PROVIDERS_FROM_SOURCES` variable to `true` before installing Airflow (see https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.rst#provider-packages) - this way you will not install the provider packages from PyPI.

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting these same warnings, and I didn't install from source:

```
pip --use-deprecated legacy-resolver install "apache-airflow==${AIRFLOW_VERSION}" "apache-airflow[mysql]==${AIRFLOW_VERSION}" --constraint "${CONSTRAINT_URL}"
```